# Unity C# ARCore - Turn on Android camera torch while the app is running

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm currently working on an app in Unity 2022.1.23f1 using the ARCore XR and AR Foundation plugins. I was wondering if it is currently possible to turn on the Android flash/torch while using the ARCore plugin. I did some digging and saw posts saying that it wasn't possible, but these were from a few years ago.

I tried a few different things to get it working, and got the following error on one of the attempts:

```
android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_IN_USE (4): setTorchMode:2024: Torch for camera "0" is not available due to an existing camera user
```

Is it still the case that it isn't possible to turn on the torch while using ARCore for android devices?

I've tried accessing the rear device camera and turning on the torch while the app is running, but got the following error:

```
android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_IN_USE (4): setTorchMode:2024: Torch for camera "0" is not available due to an existing camera user
```